# Adding Custom Code to SSRS Report, getting "End of Statement Expected Error"

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Dumb noob question:

I'm trying to include the following VBA function in the Custom Code for a SSRS 2012 report:

```
Function GetManufactureDate(ByVal Add As Integer, ByVal Target As Date) As 
Date
Dim Added As Integer = 0
Dim T As Date = Target
Do While Added > Add
T = DateAdd("d", -1, T)
If DatePart("dddd", T) = (2 <= 6) Then Added = Added - 1 End If
Loop
Return T
End Function
```

I'm adding this at the very bottom of the existing custom code, below all previous "End Functions" and other such stuff. According to Visual Studio, this code is correct, but when I try to save my SSRS report, I get "End of Statement Expected".

I have googled, and found nothing. FYI, the code is being added with the formatting I'm showing here.

I'm new with SSRS and *extremely* new with VBA, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think SSRS uses VB.NET, not VBA. That makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> If DatePart("dddd", T) = (2 <= 6) Then Added = Added - 1 End If
> ```

An `If...Then` statement that has the "Then" part on the same line as the "If" part, is using the *inline syntax*, which is delimited by the end-of-statement token (`NEWLINE`), not `End If`.

So:

```
If {bool-expression} Then {instruction}
```

Or, the *block syntax*:

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {instructions}
End If
```

Remove `End If`, the parser isn't expecting it. Or, put `Added = Added - 1` on its own line, and put `End If` on the line underneath.